# Aliasing a generic interface with a using alias directive

Tags: c#, using-directives

I am aware that it's not possible to alias a generic type (e.g. `using Foo = Dictionary;` is invalid), but that the generic type on the right must be closed (e.g. `using Foo = Dictionary<int, string>;` will work).

However, it seems like it's invalid to alias an `IDictionary<string, object>`--instead, the alias must be for just the interface `IDictionary`. The error I get is "CS0308: The non-generic type 'IDictionary' cannot be used with type arguments." Is there a way to alias this entire thing? (Or a better way to achieve what I want?)

A common thing I do in my API is for functions to take an `IDictionary<string, object>`, and I'd like to do something akin to `using ParsedObjects = IDictionary<string, object>;`. In fact, I'd like to be able to declare:

`using ParsedObjectsHandler = Func<Interaction, object, IDictionary<string, object>, Task>;`

(But I am willing to settle for just the former.)

Comment: Have you considered using delegates? You can define `ParsedObjectsHandler` delegate type with the signature you mentioned and use that directly without needing more verbose built-in generic `Func<T1, ...>` delegates.

Comment: That sounds interesting... I'll take a look at that

Comment: @V.Leon thank you, defining a new delegate type was the way to go. :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit:** Although the below answer solves the question (and I'm leaving it up as I could not find the info anywhere else), I did go with V.Lion's suggestion in the comments to define my own delegate type instead.

---

The issue was that I was attempting to use `System.Collections.IDictionary` instead of `System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary<TKey, TValue>`. Using the latter worked just fine, i.e.:

```cs
using ParsedObjects = System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary<string, object>;
```